# fontWeight is not working in new version of android studio in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I cannot able to use fontweight in flutter. I give me error when I use fontweight.

[image]

Comment: Can you try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app

Comment: What is the error message? If it's only underlined in red, it could be an IDE error. Have you restarted it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to invalidate the cache of Android Studio to see if that fixes the problem.